# New PrtScr screencast function in Jammy

Tags: sound, shortcut-keys, 22.04, desktop-recording

On Impish, PrtScr took a snapshot screen copy and stored the png file in ~/Images.
On Jammy, Alt PrtScr does the same job, storing the png file in a subdirectory of ~/Images.
Instead, PrtScr pops up a menu offering the possibility of a video screencast.

How do I stop the recording? (For my test, I closed the session...).

Also, the sound was not recorded, although my PulseAudio configuration in pavucontrol was working (tested with Audacity). Is this a bug?

This tool is highly valuable now that simplescreenrecorder does not work with Wayland.

### Thanks.
Regards.

Yves-Antoine Emmanuelli

Answer (score 0):

You stop the recording by clicking on the red square stop button on the top right corner of your Activities panel.

Comment: Hella Alina, thanks very much for your answer. It seems so obvious once somebody has told you :-). Did you manage to record sound as the same time as image ? Thanks again !

Comment: I'll use Audacity to record the sound at the same time :-) Thanks again.